# Database Associative Relation with records of same Entity

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I may not be thinking clearly but I was asked at work to visually represent relations for an existing database. I am used to associative many-to-many relations such as "**Person - PersonProfession - Profession**" (being PersonProfession the associative one).

Now I came across with a "**Person - PersonAssociation - Person**" like relation. Still is many-to-many, but each Person is associated with one or more... **Persons** (same entity).

Resuming,I got only 2 tables (**Person** and **PersonAssociation**). PersonAssociation contains only the fields [personA] and [personB]

If I draw a one-to-many line between them, I would just be saying each Person has multiple associations, without saying "what are they associated with".

This approach Looks OK to me, and so far it works good, but I have no clue how to Represent it. Anyone with a similar experience has ideas on how to represent this situation?

Thanks in Advance,
Raul Cardoso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what it would look like on an ERD. For many-to-many, there's an alternative -- depends on whether you want to explicitly show the relationship-entity. I would show such an entity in either of the following cases: where my purpose is more implementation-based, I would show it (but not if my intent was more "logical"/conceptual. Also, if the relationship itself had some attributes, I would show it (e.g. a "Friendship entity might show things like when the friendship began, etc.)

[image: Sample ERD]

Googling, I found [this PDF from a course on ERDs](http://www.msit2005.mut.ac.th/msit_media/1_2549/ITEC3610/Lecture/20060610221816yB.pdf). You might find it helpful

Comment: Thanks Darius, the picture opened my eyes to it immediatly, Specially the Many-to-Many with Friendship Entity. I think even better than the PDF explanation on this. thanks

Comment: The relation between firendship and person is suspect to me.

Comment: You're right, the crow's feet were pointing in the wrong direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To represent it ... how? You mean in a diagram of some kind? Like an Entity-Relationship Diagram?

If that's what you mean, the convventional way to represent this is to either:

(a) Draw a line from the entity back to itself;

(b) Draw a line from the entity back to itself, and put a label on the line indicating the nature of the relationship, like "reports to" or "is a cousin of" or whatever.

(c) Draw a diamond to represent the relationship, then draw a line from the entity to the relationship diamond, and another line from the relationship diamond back to the entity. Put an appropriate label inside the diamond.

BTW: This is called a "recursive relationship" and it is not at all uncommon.

Comment: (a) option would be hard to understand in this case I think. Thumbs up for (b) and (c) and the info on it's existence for a long time as "recursive relationship"!